# Determine flow meter reading from image

Tags: opencv, object-detection

currently I'm working on a project to identify the rotameter's reading. My main task is to located the rotameter from the input image, then identify the line mark from the rotameter as well as the floater. Then, I need to find out the reading of the meter based on the position of the floater. There are a few challenges faced, the glare on the meter due to illumination and the angle of the image taken. Currently, I tried with CLAHE followed by Canny edge detection. However, I was only able to get the line mark at the area without light reflection. I had also tried Inpaint + CLAHE to remove the glare part and Gaussian blurring to reduce the image noises. But most on the line marks are missing. I'm still new in computer vision and currently using Python + OpenCV. Any good suggestions?

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW7w5.jpg)

Here's the code I still trying on for Inpaint + CLAHE, and the outcome is attached.

Outcome: [Inpaint + Clahe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyHyB.png)

```
img = cv2.imread('IMG-20210630-WA0016.jpeg')
resized = cv2.resize(img, (540, 960))
crp = resized[0:960, 150:360]

# convert image from RGB to HSV
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(crp, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# Histogram equalisation on the V-channel
img_hsv[:, :, 2] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_hsv[:, :, 2])

# convert image back from HSV to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional).
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(4,4))
cl1 = clahe.apply(gray)
cv2.imshow('Clahe', cl1)

# mask = cv2.threshold(cl1, 180, 185, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
mask = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

# use mask with input to do inpainting
inpaint = cv2.inpaint(cl1, mask, 21, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", crp)
cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)

result1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(inpaint, (1, 1), 1, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
canny = cv2.Canny(result1, 100, 255)
cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)

key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For this, I just tried with CLAHE, the line marks look clearer but the position of the floater are missing.

Outcome 2: [Clahe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFQhs.png)

```
img = cv2.imread('IMG-20210630-WA0016.jpeg')
resized = cv2.resize(img, (540, 960))
crp = resized[0:960, 150:360]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(crp,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional).
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(4,4))
cl1 = clahe.apply(gray)
result1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(cl1, (3, 3), 1, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
canny = cv2.Canny(result1, 150, 255)
cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)

cv2.imshow("Source", crp)
cv2.imshow('Clahe', cl1)

key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: source pictures please. and please review [ask].

Comment: the code isn't terribly important since you say it doesn't solve the issue anyway.

Comment: "the glare on the meter due to illumination and the angle of the image taken" -- seems like you should fix/improve your image acquisition system first.

Comment: source image leaves much to be desired. lighting... with the right lighting (not more, different) you could probably make this trivial. play with a flashlight until the floating thing in the gauge clearly contrasts against the immediate background.

Comment: example: piece of paper wrapped around the back half of the gauge, lit from the back side into the gauge. that ought to give nice bright background and leave the floater appearing dark.